# Wrong dependency to IIS restart for getting changed data in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, iis

I am working on an ASP.NET webforms application with Entity Framework. Also for some reports it uses a dll and in that we have explicit query to get the records from SQL Server (such as ADO).

The problem is that when I change a column such as `ParentID` in SQL Server, I must to reset the website in IIS to see it and this solves the problem. This dependency is not logical and I want to know why this happens? Is there any relation to caching because of calling method in the dll?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you mean that you are changing the value of the ParentID column in some row or rows in the database, and you want that change to be immediately visible in the user interface?

Comment: @allmhuran exactly and this is a basic expectation we have from the web apps

Answer (score 0):

When you run a query against SQL server (or any database, really), the result that you see is not the data "in the database", so to speak. The query returns a *copy* of that data that belongs only to you. The copy of the data gets sent over the network, to the client - in your case, an ASP.NET web application - and the application does whatever it needs to do, such as show it to a user.

Once the query which retrieved the data is complete, there is no longer any link between the data in the client, and the data in the database. There is no continuous, "live" connection between the two, even if your actual database connection is still open. The database connection is merely a way to send queries to the server, and for it to send copies of the data back.

It's like taking a copy of a file from a different machine. If you copy a file from my machine, and then I update my copy, your copy doesn't instantly get updated.

If you want data in some user interface to stay perfectly up to date with the data that actually exists in the database, you have a difficult problem to solve. There is no "easy" way to do this. Or perhaps more accurately, there is no simple or *efficient* way to do this.

This might seem odd to you. You're thinking "well, why not? Why doesn't it just show me the values as they actually exist?". The reason is that these systems need to be able to support many users - often thousands at once - who are all both reading the database and writing to it. Imagine someone was in the middle of updating data in the database, but then they rollback their transaction. Should you see the data as it was being modified, but not committed? What if two users are trying to update "the same" data at once? All sorts of concurrency questions come into play, which basically boils down to questions about locking.

What you are encountering here is a basic principle of multi-threaded environments, which translates to systems with multiple clients: Data can't be accessed directly by multiple people at the same time. Instead, you give each person their own immutable copy.

In a web application things are even more disconnected. When the browser requests the web page, the *server side* of the web application gets a copy of the data from the database, and then transmits that to the browser. Once the page is loaded there is no longer any link between the web server and the database server, *or* any link between the web server and the web browser at the client, and *certainly* no link between the web browser and the database.

Ultimately, this is one of the "hard problems" in computer science. You want to know how to tell the client to invalidate their "cache", and refresh their local data. There are a few mechanisms provided by .NET to do this with SQL Server, but they are quite technical. One of them is [query notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server)

Comment: But I changed a column and then load the web page. So data has updated before sending the request and then I think this is a logical expectation to see the proper data on web.